# context or workdir for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning docker

I need to specify the working directory for a docker image, I think that'll be something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ./dir
```

Now I want to make the image `python:onbuild` to run on the `./dir`, but I dont want to create any `Dockerfile` inside the `./dir`.

The `docker-compose` manual says nothing about that.

Is it possible? How to do that?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

I think you're looking for `working_dir`. Search for "working_dir" in the [docker-compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#working_dir).

Comment: The link no longer leads to the specific section, and once I found the specific section it doesn't clearly show the location of `working_dir` within the YAML hierarchy. This blog entry turned out to be helpful: https://medium.com/gemma-black/dockers-working-dir-and-entrypoint-are-actually-important-f9028f25a4fd

Answer (score 87):

You can specify the working directory as follows.

```
version: '2'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context:    /path/to/source/dir/
      dockerfile: /path/to/custom-Dockerfile/relative/tocontextdir/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
```

Answer (score 14):

Possibly not exactly what you were looking for, but you can specify the "context" for the docker build to be a different directory to where the actual Dockerfile lives.

```
build:
  context: ./folder/containing/files
  dockerfile: path/to/dockerfile/relative/to/context/Dockerfile
```

Any ADD/COPY commands in your Dockerfile then act as if they are relative to the `context` regardless of where the Dockerfile actually is.

Answer (score 4):

The [build configuration in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/build) just ends up in a call to `docker build`, so you need to have a Dockerfile to use that workflow.

As the [docs for python:onbuild](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) say, you can start with a minimal Dockerfile that just contains `FROM python:onbuild`. But as they also say, `:onbuild` isn't a great option, you'll have much more control building your own Dockerfile `FROM python`.